# Markov models that with several active states

Tags: prediction, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Are there any Markov-like models that can have several active states?

So say if trying to determine (the chance) when the person will wake up based on two variables (weather and the time the person went to bed).

**Target** Wake up `early` / `late`

**States**

- Went to bed `early` / `late`
- Morning is `sunny` / `cloudy`

**EDIT** Pardon me for not explaining further:
In this case we know (for example) that a person went to bed `late`, but it will be `sunny` in the morning.
Obviously both of those known states are important.

**Realization** I've been thinking of the problem upside down. Instead of thinking of `bedtime` and `sunshine` as states, I should be thinking of them as observations, and `wake up time` as the state! (even though the flow of time is in reverse - the state occurs after the observations)

PS. Would that even be a Markov model?

Comment: What is the goal? Is there a reason why the combination of states cannot be enumerated and a single state be created?

Comment: I do not fully understand the question because I am unsure of the terminology. In the context of Markov models generally, exactly what is the definition of an "active state" and how does it differ from a "state"?

Comment: @whuber, there are absorbing states, from which there's no escape. OP probably calls active those states which are not absorbing

Comment: @Aksakal That guess doesn't really seem to make sense in this context.

Comment: Yes, markov models can have exogenous variables. The Markov model is a model where the current state and a few states in the past capture all information that is relevant for expectation of the future state, i.e. the memory is not infinite.